# how to group by keys with respect of some part of values in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file with `keys` and `Results` . The result has 3 parts. like this:

```
df.json()[0]['Results'][0]

{'categoryId': '2674',
 'categoryName': 'software engineer',
 'score': '1.0377672767639161'}
```

I want to collect all `keys` who have the same `categoryName` in the result. and then count them. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of different `categoryName`s, or the number of elements in each group?

Comment: Also, please give a broader example of not just one result + the expected output

Comment: the number of elements in each group

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be iterating over every group in one of the following ways: if you just want to know the count of one group you can do this:

```py
category_name = "software engineer"
count = 0
for cat in df.json()[0]['Results']:
    if cat['categoryName'] == category_name:
        count += 1
```

If you want to count all categories at the same time you can do that as well:

```py
category_count = {}
for cat in df.json()[0]['Results']:
   category = cat['categoryName']
   if category in category_count.keys():
       category_count[category] += 1
    else:
        category_count[category] = 1
```

to get the corresponding keys you can do:

```py
category_count = {}
for key, cat in enumerate(df.json()[0]['Results']):
   category = cat['categoryName']
   if category in category_count.keys():
       category_count[category].append(key)
    else:
        category_count[category] = [key]
```

that way you can get all keys with the `categoryName="software engineer"` like this: `category_count["software_engineer"]`

Comment: Not very Pythonic

Comment: I do not have categoryNames