# how to group some part of a list's information?

Tags: python, list, collections, set

I have a list each element of list is like this:

```
 list[0]={'Keywords': 'program manager',
 'result': {'categoryId': '2712',
  'categoryName': 'program manager',
  'score': '0.9506622791290285'},
 'categoryId': '2712'}
 {'Keywords': 'technicalfunctional consultant', 'result': []}
```

I need to collect all keywords whose have the same `categoryName`. I did the following :

```
output1 = defaultdict(set)
for entry in list:
    kwds = entry['Keywords'].strip().split(' ')
    for word in kwds:
        output1[entry.get('categoryId', None)].add(word)
```

But it split all words and I don't want it. is there any way to collect all keywords with the same  `categoryName`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to group by keys with respect of some part of values in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794487/how-to-group-by-keys-with-respect-of-some-part-of-values-in-python)

Comment: But it is counting write? I need the `keywords`

Comment: I've edited the answer to adjust for that. Take a look again

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the existent categoryIds in the dataset, then build a dict that for each one of them contains all the keywords associated.

EDIT: Changed the code to have a MRE and changed the name of the list to `list1`

Code:

```
list1=[]
list1.append({'Keywords': 'program manager',
'result': {'categoryId': '2712',
'categoryName': 'program manager',
'score': '0.9506622791290285'},
'categoryId': '2712'})

cat_set = set([elem["result"]["categoryName"] for elem in list1])

cat_dict = {}

for cat_name in cat_set:
    cat_dict[cat_name] = [elem["Keywords"] for elem in list1 if elem["result"]["categoryName"] == cat_name]
```

Comment: I get this error: `KeyError: 'categoryId'
`

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: It works for me, change the list name to list1 (and its references)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Changed my answer, just copy it. Don't name lists list since that's the keyword for the list type

Comment: I have another name for that but give me error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: The code I wrote works, there's something wrong in how you integrate it. Check types, you are trying to access a value in a dict but the dict is actually a list

Comment: your code works for me too. where is the problem? I can't see it

Comment: some of keywords might not have any categoryName. do you think it is a problem?How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist=[{'Keywords': 'scrum master',
  'result': {'categoryId': '3193',
   'categoryName': 'agile coach',
   'score': '1.0'},
  'categoryId': '3193'},
 {'Keywords': 'principal consultant',
  'result': {'categoryId': '2655',
   'categoryName': 'principal consultant',
   'score': '1.045369052886963'},
  'categoryId': '2655'},{'Keywords': 'technicalfunctional consultant', 'result': []}]
def keywordcollector(yourlist):
    yourlist=list(filter(lambda x:type(x['result'])==type({}),yourlist))
    categories=set(x['result']['categoryName'] for x in yourlist)
    keywordslist=[]
    for category in categories:
        temp_list=list(filter(lambda x:x['result']['categoryName']==category,yourlist))
        temp_keywords=list(map(lambda x:x['Keywords'],temp_list))
        keywordslist.append({category:temp_keywords})
    return keywordslist
print(keywordcollector(mylist))
```

The code above gives you dictionary object with keywords for every categoryname. The code outputs

```
[{'principal consultant': ['principal consultant']}, {'agile coach': ['scrum master']}]
```

Comment: error for `categories=set(x['result']['categoryName'] for x in yourlist)` : `categories=set(x['result']['categoryName'] for x in yourlist)`

Comment: what error? can you paste the error code?.

Comment: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Pass the whole list to the function not every element.

Comment: wait i will paste the code that i tested with output

Comment: pass your list to the function. if every element of your list object is a dictionary object as you typed it should work fine. keywordcollector(yourlist)

Comment: I pass the whole list

Comment: give me error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: The error means you have another list inside your list. Are you sure each object of your list is of type dictionary. it seems every object of your list is another list object. Which is not what you mentioned in the post.

Comment: I have the same data as I posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811068/how-i-can-fix-this-error-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-no

Comment: some of keywords might not have any `categoryName`. do you think it is a problem?

Comment: [{'agile coach': ['scrum master']}, {'principal consultant': ['principal consultant']}]

Comment: if the error at the line you mentioned , i am assuming you are passing a nested list to the function. i dont know what else is wrong.

Comment: some of keywords might not have any categoryName. do you think it is a problem? how I can fix it?

Comment: I am pretty sure if the error is a TypeError thrown at line categories=set(x['result']['categoryName'] for x in yourlist), then it means the yourlist object passed to the function has a list object instead of a dictionary object.

Comment: TypeError happens when we try to access a list object with a string. for example a=[1,2,3] and when i try a['hello'] it throws Type error list indices must be integers

Comment: `type(mylist)= list`, but when I pass `mylist[1:3]` it is working

Comment: try for x in mylist:print(type(x))

Comment: if every element of the list is of type dictionary you wont  get type error, there might be something of list type in between.

Comment: try this input`{'Keywords': 'technicalfunctional consultant', 'result': []}`

Comment: Okay, so your list has an empty list where the code expects a dictionary object. I will edit my code to skip such objects

Comment: oh my god, what is this error now `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: I have no clue why error is thrown again, which line is it?? your input source is not consistent with the object you posted.

Comment: it is first line, a guy answered me correctly

Comment: can I use for dic?

Comment: Technicallly the only object that my code call's is the function keywordcollector. I have no clue why you get that error on first line. The error you mentioned when a list object is called. For example a=[123]; a() Throws that type of error.